# Is there an api call to reset the Microsoft AD azure app registration secret id value

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Is there an api call to reset the Microsoft AD azure app registration secret id value? Can someone please help me with documentation or postman examples?

If I have to create the token on Microsoft app registration to get the bearer token for authorization, is this the way to set-up? Which claim should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Logic App

You can use the HTTP connector to make the call.

[image]

### REST

You can use the **addPassword** method `POST /applications/{id}/addPassword`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

### PowerShell

```
$passwordCred = @{
        "displayName" = $appRegNewSecretName
        "endDateTime" = (Get-Date).AddDays($newSecretExpiryDays)
}
    
$newSecretObj = $null
 
# Send the request and get the new password
$newSecretObj = Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId $appRegObject.Id -PasswordCredential $passwordCred
 
if (!$newSecretObj) {
         Write-Error "Something went wrong. Unable to set the secret for $appRegId. Aborting."
         throw
}
```

Credit: https://rakhesh.com/azure/graph-cmdlets-and-azure-ad-app-registrations/

Comment: Thank you, I would like to make api call but it needs bearer token. How to generate that?

Comment: If you are trying to do powershell look here. https://github.com/kenrward/GraphAPIAppPermissions/blob/main/get-enterpriseapps.ps1  The first 40 lines will show you how to do it.

Comment: I was planning to write AWS lambda function to make this api call.

Comment: I don't know Lambda but I added a pic to show how you could use the HTTP connector in an Azure Logic app to make the call.  Azure Functions support Powershell if you wanted to try that.  I am sure there is a way to do this with Lambda but as a MSFT employee, I am biased towards Azure.

Comment: I see the powershell implementation, thanks for that. I was trying to make this api call work through postman so that I could implement it through lambda. So to explain I have this app registration for which I need to change secret-id value but the bearer token should be generated for Azure user? I do not see an option to configure that on Azure portal for that admin user. Or is it that I am picturing this wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the docs here that talks about how to use delegated permissions to allow your application to sign in as a user.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis#specify-the-permissions-your-app-requires-to-access-the-office-365-management-apis